# TypeError: object of type 'property' has no len()

Tags: python, class, object, properties, attributes

I have this code of a class that contains a list `_offers` of custom `Offer` objects. For this list I created a property to allow access to it:

```
class OffersManager:    
    _offers: list[Offer] = []
    
    @property
    def offers(cls) -> list[Offer]:
        return cls._offers
```

The problem is that the program treats this list as a "property" object, so it gives me an error when I try to get the length of the list:

```
>>> len(OffersManager.offers)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
        len(OffersManager.offers)
    TypeError: object of type 'property' has no len()
```

Can someone tell me the correct way to make a property return the attribute as a list?

Comment: You should be accessing `offers` from an *instance* of `OffersManager`, not the class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update from the comments: this is deprecated and may not work correctly, use the metaclass approach from [SUTerliakov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196477/4854821) instead.

---

You need to mark the property as a class method, so it's bound to the class itself rather than the instances:

```python
class OffersManager:    
    _offers: list[OfferData] = []
    
    @classmethod
    @property
    def offers(cls) -> list[OfferData]:
        return cls._offers
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will emphasize to those who will encounter the problem in the future, that the order of the decorators is important (I tried to reverse them and got the same error).

Comment: This isn't recommended; the machinery that lets you define "class" properties is deprecated; the documentation suggests it has been removed from Python 3.11 (though it still seems to work in that version).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that! For future reference, the Python 3.11 [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#language-builtins) entry.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid deprecated functionality which never used to work properly, you can define your property on a metaclass:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeAlias

OfferData: TypeAlias = int


class OffersManagerMeta(type):
    _offers: list[OfferData] = []
    
    @property
    def offers(cls) -> list[OfferData]:
        return cls._offers


class OffersManager(metaclass=OffersManagerMeta):
    pass


print(OffersManager.offers)
OffersManager._offers = [1, 2]
print(OffersManager.offers)
```

And this even [passes](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=3199a3a4022887120573d7b3dca5585b)
strict `mypy`.

Comment: Genuine question: Why did you use inherit from type in the OffersManagerMeta?

Comment: @BartekLachowicz `type` is the default metaclass. All metaclasses must ultimately inherit from `type`.